# How to return a array from array of object based on multiple keys

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object having with multiple value but I have to filter values based on keys into an array and also merge value to array having same value. I have tried in different steps can it be done in single map/filter/reduce?

```
const a = [
    {abc: ['add', 'edit'], cond: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work'], def: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx'], work: ['view_work', 'delete_work']},
];
const expected result = {
    cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'],  matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work','view_work', 'delete_work']
}

const b = a.map(el => el.cond);

const c = a.map(el => el.matx);

const d = a.map(el => el.work);

result = {cond: [...b], matx: [...c], work: [...d]}
```

Comment: please add the real result. you have two results. which one is the wanted?

Comment: pls chk in expected result, other one is what i tried from my side

Comment: Looking at your expected result, seems that you need to get an object that has unique keys taken from given/initial array 'const a', and each key needs to have for a value an array of all the unique values from 'const a' that have that key as their substring? Also, you need only cond, matx and work as keys? Did I understand it right?

Comment: So replace your constants b c d with your expression and filter... but note that your values are in arrays so please explain how do you know at which place a 'view_cond' will appear? By comparing the strings or are the placeholders? Note that you can unpack and repack dictionaries by Object.entries and Object.assign to execute a Array.filter function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all wanted properties' values into a set and build a new object from the key/value pairs.

```js
const
    data = [{ abc: ['add', 'edit'], cond: [] }, { cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work'], def: [] }, { cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx'], work: ['view_work', 'delete_work'] }],
    keys = ['cond', 'matx', 'work'],
    addToSet = (s, v) => s.add(v),
    result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [
        k, 
        [...data.reduce((r, o) => (o[k] || []).reduce(addToSet, r), new Set)]
    ]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a single `reduce` method. All keys are evaluated dynamically, so no matter how many keys you add/remove to your objects you get dynamically added keys:

```js
const a = [
    {abc: ['add', 'edit'], cond: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work'], def: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx'], work: ['view_work', 'delete_work']},
];


const result = a.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  // get all keys
  const keys = Object.keys(cur);

  // add each key and related values one by one
  keys.forEach(el => {
    if(prev[el] === undefined)
      prev[el] = []
    prev[el].push(cur[el])
    // remove duplicates
    prev[el] = prev[el].flat()
  })
  return prev
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with forEach ...  `.map()` and `.filter()` will always return an array not an object.

```js
const a = [
    {abc: ['add', 'edit'], cond: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work'], def: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx'], work: ['view_work', 'delete_work']},
];
const result = {cond: [], work: [], matx: []}



a.forEach(x=> { x.cond && result.cond.push(...x.cond); 
                x.work && result.work.push(...x.work);
                 x.matx && result.work.push(...x.matx);
                 }

);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You state: "It cant be done with forEach" then proceed to show how it "can"? Perhaps update your answer to clarify and remove all the extra white space in the code

Comment: I misspelled cant, thx for point out. I wanned to write "can". Answer eddited.

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = [
  { abc: ["add", "edit"], cond: [] },
  {
    cond: ["add_cond", "edit_cond", "view_cond"],
    matx: ["add_matx", "edit_matx", "delete_matx"],
    work: ["add_work", "edit_work"],
    def: [],
  },
  {
    cond: ["add_cond", "edit_cond", "view_cond", "delete_cond"],
    matx: ["add_matx", "edit_matx", "view_matx", "store_matx"],
    work: ["view_work", "delete_work"],
  },
];

function mapper(a) {
  let result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    result = Object.assign(a[i], a[i + 1]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(mapper(a));
```

RESULT--->

```
{
  cond: [ 'add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond' ],
  matx: [ 'add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx' ],
  work: [ 'view_work', 'delete_work' ],
  def: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on that you only want arrays you only miss `.forEach` to iterate combined with `.filter` and most forEach-anwers here are wrong (values appear multiple times in `result`) you can simple go through your structure and break down the problem.

First iterating over all values of `a` and
than over every dictionary entry of the current value like `abc` or `cond` only if you want that one in your result and
than decide if a value like `add_cond` is already included in `result['cond']` and if not `.push` it:

```js
const a = [
    {abc: ['add', 'edit'], cond: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work'], def: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx'], work: ['view_work', 'delete_work']},
];

const result = {cond: [], matx: [], work: []}
a.forEach( // forEach feed a function with args value, index, reference proof it by (...args) => {console.log(args)}
  current_dict => {
    Object.entries(current_dict).filter(current_entry => current_entry[0] in result).forEach(
      current_entry => {
        current_entry[1].filter(value => !result[current_entry[0]].includes(value)).forEach( // note that this filtering can be done with an if statement in the forEach
          value => {
            result[current_entry[0]].push(value)
          }
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
console.log(result)
```

Note that the arrays are not ordered. Cause you give me no answer on my comment I do not know if you want to retain a special order (your expected result is not alphabetical orderd too) or if only one occurence in an array is enough.

You should use dictionaries instead arrays like `add_cond: true` so you need no addressing by index and no order and can do a simply `key in result['cond']` operation or
a type of mapping function like `condIndexFunction(option){/*something*/return index}` after you give your `result['cond']` an array with fixed size like `new Array(5)` so than you can test later with `result['cond'][condIndexFunction('cond_add')] != null`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why its not the same as the expected result but try this:

```js
const a = [
    {abc: ['add', 'edit'], cond: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work'], def: []},
    {cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'], matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx'], work: ['view_work', 'delete_work']},
];
const expectedResult = {
    cond: ['add_cond', 'edit_cond', 'view_cond', 'delete_cond'],  matx: ['add_matx', 'edit_matx', 'view_matx', 'store_matx', 'delete_matx'], work: ['add_work', 'edit_work','view_work', 'delete_work']
}

const result = a.reduce(
  (prev, curr) => ({
    cond: [...new Set([...prev.cond, ...curr.cond || []])],
    matx: [...new Set([...prev.matx, ...curr.matx || []])],
    work: [...new Set([...prev.work, ...curr.work || []])],
  }),
  { cond: [], matx: [], work: [] }
);

console.log("Expected cond: ", expectedResult.cond);
console.log("Actual cond:   ", result.cond);
console.log("Expected matx: ", expectedResult.matx);
console.log("Actual matx:   ", result.cond);
console.log("Expected work: ", expectedResult.work);
console.log("Actual work:   ", result.cond);
```